# Add text to excel cells with vba in word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

In Word program, with the following VBA code, I can copy from an Excel file cell:

```
Dim MyExcel As Excel.Application
Dim MyWB As Excel.Workbook
Set MyExcel = New Excel.Application
Set MyWB = MyExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...\Desktop\test.xlsx")
    MyWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Copy
MyWB.Close False
Set MyExcel = Nothing
Set MyWB = Nothing
```

But I could not enter a value in the Excel file with the following line change code:

```
MyWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "123"
```

or

```
MyWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).paste
```

Do you have a suggestion for this?

Comment: If you look in Object Browser you will see that there isn't a `Paste` method for a `Range`, only `PasteSpecial`. That said when testing it here on O365 `PasteSpecial` causes Excel to crash without an error message. However, in my testing `MyWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "123"` does work. Perhaps you're not seeing it because your code closes the workbook without saving the changes.

Comment: Make sure that the Excel Object Library is checked in Tools.References in your Word host.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Timothy Rylatt. Changes were observed by adding the "Save" code.

Comment: If option "Excel Object Library" is not enabled, the copy command will not be executed. So I have already enabled option "Excel Object Library". Thanks for the reply @freeflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
MyWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).pasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but this method has been tried before and gives an error. Thanserror "1004" @Wasif Hasan